# How to handle the promise of a fetch without nested callbacks?

Tags: javascript, promise, fetch

I guess that fetch returns a promise. But how do I handle it nicely? The code below does not quite work. I get `{message: "Internal server error custom: TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined"}`.

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    try {
        getDiscourseId(username, callback).then((userId) => {
            callback(null, {
                statusCode: 200,
                headers: {},
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    userId: userId
                })
            });
        });

    } catch (error) {
        callback(null, {
            statusCode: 500,
            headers: {},
            body: JSON.stringify({
                message: "Internal server error custom: " + error
            })
        });
    }
};

function getDiscourseId(username) {
    console.log({username: username, discourseApiKey: discourseApiKey, discourseApiUser: discourseApiUser})
    fetch(`https://${domain}/users/${username}.json?api_key=${discourseApiKey}&api_username=${discourseApiUser}`, {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'Accept': 'application/json'
        },
        method: 'GET',
    })
    .then(response => {
        return response.json();
    })
    .then(data => {
        if (data) {
            return data.user.id; 
        }
    })
    .catch(err => {
        return {err: err};
    });
}
```

Comment: You forgot to `return` from `getDiscourseId`.

Comment: ^^ it goes right before the `fetch` call on the second line of the function.

Comment: Separately: You're not handling request failure correctly, you need to check the `.ok` (or `.status`) property. You're not alone, so many people fail to do this check that [I wrote an article about it on my anemic little blog](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2018/06/common-fetch-errors.html).

Comment: Lastly: This looks like Node.js code. In any recent version of Node.js, you can use an `async` function and `await` to avoid explicit promise handling, letting you just write the logical flow of the code.

Comment: What is the username you pass to the getDiscourseId in try statment ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting that error because your `getDiscourseId` function does not return a value.

If you add the keyword `return` in front of your `fetch(...)` call, you should start making some headway.

You'll probably also want to remove the `.catch` from inside `getDiscourseId` and instead add it to the end of the **call** to `getDiscourseId` inside your handler:

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    getDiscourseId(username)
        .then((userId) => {
            callback(null, {
                statusCode: 200,
                headers: {},
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    userId: userId
                })
            });
        })
        .catch(error => {
            callback(null, {
                statusCode: 500,
                headers: {},
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    message: "Internal server error custom: " + error
                })
            });
        });
};

function getDiscourseId(username) {
    console.log({username: username, discourseApiKey: discourseApiKey, discourseApiUser: discourseApiUser})
    return fetch(`https://${domain}/users/${username}.json?api_key=${discourseApiKey}&api_username=${discourseApiUser}`, {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'Accept': 'application/json'
        },
        method: 'GET',
    })
    .then(response => {
        if (!response.ok) { // h/t TJ Crowder
            throw new Error("Failed with HTTP code " + response.status);
        }
        return response.json();
    })
    .then(data => {
        if (data) {
            return data.user.id;
        }
    });
}
```

**EDIT:** TJ Crowder is correct that you probably want to treat 4xx and 5xx responses as full-fledged errors. I shamelessly stole his example code from his blog and added it to the above.

Answer (score 0):

Stop when you return the response.json(). This returns a promise, for which .then can be used.

You are returning the userId which .then cannot be used for.

If you stop at the return response.json(), you can use the '.then' statement that you already have (data.user.id => ...).